# Movesense RAM, variable allocation

Tags: movesense

With 1.6.2 why I can build code with

```
byte data[100000000];
```

If I remember correctly with previous versions I got error as there is limited RAM. I assume more correct way would be something

```
byte* data=new byte[10000];
if (data!=NULL) ...
```

Sorry for basic C/C++ question

Answer (score 0):

If you add that first code inside a function or method, it gets allocated from the stack during runtime. That's why the linker will not warn you about it. If you add it as a global variable (outside methods & classes) the error will occur. While the "new" operator works sometimes in Movesense, it is not the recommended way to allocate memory. The memory allocation routines are declared in the *movesense.h* -file:

```
void* memalloc(size_t size);
void* memcalloc(size_t size);
void memfree(void* ptr);
```

However there is an easier way. Since users *LaunchableModules* are allocated from the Movesense HEAP, you can just declare any fixed size buffers you need as class members and they will be automatically allocated when the LaunchableModule is instantiated. Although it is a good idea to query the free memory while sensor is running, before adding large buffer allocations to Module, so that you don't end up in sensor that keeps reseting every time it tries to boot because it runs out of HEAP.